# How to pass Fullcalendar start date to a form in JSP?

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, fullcalendar

I want to show the selected startDate and endDate in the  as a text box value in the same Jsp, I am using Java and struts2. Can any one tell me the correct syntax. The below syntax is giving me a null value

Script 1 I tried:

```
select : function( startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view ){
$.post("login_success_fr.jsp",{start : startDate});
$('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');
},
```

Script 2 I tried:

```
select : function( startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view ){
var startDate=startDate;   
$.post("login_success_fr.jsp",{start : startDate});
$('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');
},
```

Script 3 I tried:

```
select : function( startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view ){
var start=startDate;   
$.post("login_success_fr.jsp",{start : start});
$('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');
},
```

My form in JSP:

```
   <div id="calEventDialog">
    <s:form action="ScheduleDialogFormSubmit" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="25%">Start Time</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dialogForm.startTime" value="**<%=request.getParameter("start")%>**" tabindex="1" size="25"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <s:form>
```

Please help me find the correct syntax for displaying start date and time.

Comment: startDate should give you the correct value in the select callback. Can you do a console.log(startDate) and see what value you are getting?

Comment: i am getting back result as `undefined` for this